# ¿Error psr-4 al hacer un deploy de mi proyecto Laravel PHP en ECS de Amazon AWS?

Tags: php, laravel, aws, composer, ec2

Luego de subir un comprimido con mi proyecto a AWS EC2, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Class Modules\Modulo1\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX located in ./Modules/Modulo1/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX..php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Models\XXX located in ./app/Models/XXX.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

1- No sé absolutamente nada de AWS, recién estoy intentando aprender.

2- En local cuando hago "composer update" me salen esos "skipping" pero nunca me devuelve "error code 1".

¿Cómo puedo hacer para evitar que salga el error code 1 y sólamente me muestre los "Skipping"?